# Maze solver cannot find exit

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Maze
{
    private int[][] maze;
    private boolean exitFound;

    public Maze()
    {
        exitFound = false;
        maze = new int[0][0];
    }

    public Maze(int size, String line)
    {
        exitFound=false;
        maze = new int[size][size];
        int spot=0;

        for(int r= 0; r<maze.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c =0; c<maze[r].length; c++)
            {

                maze[r][c]=(line.charAt(spot*2)-48);
                spot++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkForExitPath(int r, int c)
{

    if (r >= 0 && r <maze.length &&c >= 0 && c < maze[0].length && maze[r][c] == 1)
    {

        checkForExitPath(r + 1, c);
        checkForExitPath(r - 1, c);
        checkForExitPath(r, c + 1);
        checkForExitPath(r, c - 1);
        maze[r][c] = 7;  

        if (r == maze.length-1 && c == maze[0].length-1){
            this.exitFound =true;
        }

    }
}

    public String toString()
    {
        String hol = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<maze.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j<maze[0].length; j++){
                hol += " ";
                if(maze[i][j] == 7){
                    hol += "1";

                }
                else
                {
                    hol += maze[i][j];

                }

            }
            hol += "\n";

        }
        if(this.exitFound)
        {
            hol+= "exit found";

        }
        else {
            hol += "exit not found";
        }
        return hol;
    }
}
```

That is my maze class the method checkForExitPath is not working or at least I think because everytime I run the maze solver with this runner class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MazeRunner
{
    public static void main( ) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("maze.dat"));
        while(file.hasNext())
        {
            int size = file.nextInt();
            file.nextLine();
            Maze test = new Maze(size, file.nextLine());
            test.checkForExitPath(0,0);
            out.println(test);
        }
    }
}
```

The only output I get is that an exit is not found, but I can find an exit.
I am doing this recursively.

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to solve the problem an that is the method closes after the first if statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole method does not really work recursively. If the upper left corner has a 1 which I interpret from your code as walkable way, it is changed to 7 and your method ends without recursion.
I think the four recursive method calls should be part of the first if block and no else block is necessary.

Comment: I changed it but i get an errow saying java.langstackoverflow null error

Comment: can you help me it would mean a lot to me

Comment: Now you created an endless loop. The recursive calls should be after the assignment of 7 (walked over it), otherwise you will walk back and forth between two tiles, the lower left and the one above it I would say.